# RegEx for extracting entire path from the string based on ending path

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write Regex which can extract path for my specified folder from the below path environment. For example, I want to get all the path where \php ends.

```
Path=E:\Sencha\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.2.67;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;E:\nodejs\;C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;E:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Users\Asif\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;E:\Android\ant\bin;E:\Android\android-sdk\tools;E:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;e:\xampp\php
```

For this I write following RegEx.

```
/.\:[\w\W]+\\php/
```

But it returning entire path. The expected result should be like below because there is two entry which ends with php.

```
E:\xampp\php
e:\xampp\php
```

I'm using PHP as my programming language.

Comment: this sounds like an xy problem. What exactly do you need? try `var_dump($_SERVER)` see if you see the info in there

Comment: I'm creating windows service with php so just want to get the path to the php.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ([^;]*?php)
```

Use this, See demo,

http://regex101.com/r/aM3lT9/2

Comment: Thanks. All other also correct but I marked this as first answer.

Comment: Thanx @Jonny5 on my way to catch u soon :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('/(;|Path=)([^;]*php)/', $string, $m);
var_dump($m[2]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "E:\xampp\php"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "e:\xampp\php"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
[^;=]+\\php
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d36_gssxoKjcNsIr)